# how to access label control in repeater for perticular row

Tags: c#

i have to set label visibility true or false in repeater. I have to access that label on onclick event of linkbutton. both label and linkbutton are in repeater. so when i click on hide link button i have to hide label and when click on show i have to display.but i didn't get label control of that perticular. onclick event of linkbutton only perticular row should change.

```
 protected void lnkshow_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnkshow = (LinkButton)sender;
        //RepeaterItemCollection rc = rList.Items;
        int intSOid=Convert.ToInt32(lnkshow.CommandArgument);

    // update flag into database as hide or show
    string flag = ARIData.updateIntoInvoiceItemsTable(intSOid);
    if (flag == "Y")
    {
        lnkshow.Text = "Show";
    }
    else
    {
        lnkshow.Text = "Hide";
    }
    RepeaterItemCollection rc = rList.Items;

    Label lbreakdown = default(Label);
    foreach (RepeaterItem Item in rc)
    {
        lbreakdown = (Label)Item.FindControl("lBreakdown");
        if (flag == "Y")
        {
            lbreakdown.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            lbreakdown.Visible = true;
        }

    }



}
```

this code changes whole rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the `NamingContainer` of the `LinkButton` to the `RepeaterItem`, then you have all you need to `FindControl` the label:

```
LinkButton lnkshow = (LinkButton)sender;
int intSOid = Convert.ToInt32(lnkshow.CommandArgument);
string flag = ARIData.updateIntoInvoiceItemsTable(intSOid);

RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem) lnkshow;
Label lbreakdown = (Label) item.FindControl("lbreakdown");
lbreakdown.Visible = flag != "Y"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use the Item Command event of the repeater. Then you can use the following code to get a control from the repeater item:

```
int intSOid=Convert.ToInt32(lnkshow.CommandArgument);
// update flag into database as hide or show
string flag = ARIData.updateIntoInvoiceItemsTable(intSOid);

RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
LinkButton lnkshow = (LinkButton)item.FindControl("lnkshow");
Label lbreakdown = (Label)item.FindControl("lBreakdown");

lnkshow.Text =  flag == "Y" ? "Show" : "Hide";
lbreakdown.Visible = flag != "Y";
```